# Generate custom unique key (composite key) based on two column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to generate custom unique key (composite key) based on two column during insert data with concurrency handling as many user there try to create bills.

Billno should be start with B01 to B02,B03... N until payment type and year change.

Here is expected data into table after complete insertion.

```
BillId     PaymentType     Year      BillNo
1          Card            2018      B01
2          Card            2018      B02
3          Card            2019      B01
4          Cash            2018      C01
5          Cash            2018      C02
6          Cash            2018      C03
7          PayTM           2019      P01
```

Note: I have accomplish this by update and insert trigger but looking some other option due to performance issue.

I appreciated if anyone has solution.

Comment: In description you have written B001 mean 00 and in BillNo expected output you have written B01, B02 means only one 0. which is correct?

Comment: @SurajKumar It was an error, just changed it.

Comment: You have B01 twice, should be changed on year 2019?

Comment: @Zhorov Sorry but i am not getting you.

Comment: @EzLo Yes Exactly

Comment: I strongly suggest generating a BillNo that doesn't depend on previous inserted records or you will start to have concurrency nightmares and/or preformance issues. Does your numbering have to be sequential or can it just be PaymenType + BillId?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the numbering and `DENSE_RANK` for the letters:

```
;WITH WindowFunctions AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                PaymentType,
                Year
            ORDER BY
                BillId),
        DenseRank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PaymentType, Year)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    T.*,
    BillNo = CHAR(64 + T.DenseRank) + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.RowNumber), 2)
FROM
    WindowFunctions AS T
```

Keep an eye on the amount of possible letters, might get off with the `CHAR` function.

Results:

```
BillID  PaymentType Year    RowNumber   DenseRank   BillNo
1       Card        2018    1           1           A01
2       Card        2018    2           1           A02
3       Card        2019    1           2           B01
4       Cash        2018    1           3           C01
5       Cash        2018    2           3           C02
6       Cash        2018    3           3           C03
7       PayTM       2019    1           4           D01
```

**However**, this approach will only work if you are contemplating the whole set on the same `SELECT`. Once the table is loaded and the `BillNo` are set, you won't be able to generate the next `BillNo` unless you consider previous records with another `SELECT`, and that can become tricky.

If you really need a 1 column key, I suggest generating an ID that doesn't depend on other/previous records, like mixing the `PaymentType` with the `BillId`.

Comment: Thanks but i am looking something during insert data not pulling data.

Comment: What about concurrency ?

Comment: Please add further detail on your question then, you need custom sequences by payment/year.